# How can I set a title that starts with comma, semicolon or equal sign?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, title, titlebar

Obviously it is possible to set title that contains cmd's standard delimiters but through `TITLE` command looks impossible to set a title that starts with a delimiter.

It is possible to create a new instance of CMD with such title:

```
start "==" cmd.exe
```

but not possible for the same instance.

It is possible also with .NET and `Console.Title` property but when it's called from batch file the tile lasts as long as the compiled exe runs:

```
@if (@X)==(@Y) @end /* JScript comment
@echo off
setlocal

for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%v in ('dir /b /s /a:-d  /o:-n "%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\*jsc.exe"') do (
   set "jsc=%%v"
)

if not defined jsc (
        echo !!! Installation of .NET framework needed !!!
        pause
        exit /b 3
)

rem echo %jsc%
::if not exist "%~n0.exe" (
        del /q /f %~n0.exe
        call "%jsc%" /nologo /out:"%~n0.exe" "%~dpsfnx0"
::)

call %~n0.exe %*

endlocal & exit  /b %errorlevel%


*/

import System;

var arguments:String[] = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
//Console.WriteLine(Console.Title);
if (arguments.length>0){
         Console.Title=arguments[1];
}
//Console.WriteLine(Console.Title);
```

(Probably is possible through code injection)

Is there a windows 'native' way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Win7 x64, I can produce it when a linefeed is in front of the problematic characters.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set LF=^



title !LF!,bc
```

In Win7 there seems no difference in the height or position of the title when LF is used.

Tested with

```
cmd /V:on
@for /L %n in (1 1 1111) do @(title !LF!=Hello& title +Hello)
```

But the current program is shown for the time it's running in the title, so the `TITLE` command itself produces a flicker.

Comment: Yep , this is the solution ,but there's a little bit more :-)

Comment: That is interesting.  It looks like the TITLE is then higher in the Window pane.  Almost like you could get two lines into the TITLE.

Answer (score 3):

I found another way:

```
title ^A,string
```

where `^A` is produced by entering `0` `1` while holding down the `ALT`-key ( `<pressALT><0><1><releaseALT>` ).

You can get it into a file with `echo ^A>>batch.bat` and then moving it to the correct position with notepad (it's not shown in notepad, like a whitespace; broader than a space, but not as broad as a TAB)

Comment: plus one but check my answer.Some characters are not displayed in the console title but if you use AppActivate or Tasklist  they will be detected.

Answer (score 2):

The `LF` is the answer to the question , but there's also a workaround. I think I've checked all the ASCII characters and looks like [FS and GS](http://ss64.com/ascii.html)  characters are not displayed in  title of command prompt (here's an example with `FS`):

```
@echo off 
setlocal 
::dbenham's hexprint was used here 
::http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=23888 
::Define a Linefeed variable 
set LF=^ 


::above 2 blank lines are critical - do not remove. 

::Create a FS variable 
call :hexprint "0x1C" FS 

title %FS%=;= 
exit /b 

:hexPrint  string  [rtnVar] 
  for /f eol^=^%LF%%LF%^ delims^= %%A in ( 
    'forfiles /p "%~dp0." /m "%~nx0" /c "cmd /c echo(%~1"' 
  ) do if "%~2" neq "" (set %~2=%%A) else echo(%%A 
exit /b
```

But this is not a 'perfect' solution as **AppActivate** or **Tasklist** command will detect the `FS` and `GS` characters (no such problem with `LF`).
Also `SOH` character can be used but it is displayed as space.

FS can be produced also with ctrl+]

GS with ctrl+\

SOH with ctrl+A