# Set CMD title to a forward slash and a question mark (batch)

Tags: batch-file

I am wondering if it is possible to change CMD's window title to `/?`

I've tried using `^/?`, `^/^?`, and `"/?"` but none of them seem to work.

Anyone got any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: `title "/?"` works for me. Edit: oops just realized that it displays `"/?"` with quotes

Comment: in PowerShell `[System.Console]::Title = "/?"` will just work, but if we call powershell from cmd it'll start a subshell so we can't keep the old environment

Comment: I somewhat found a workaround. If you type `start "/?"` it opens another CMD window with the correct title of `/?`. Unfortunately, this needs to open another window, and it can't just be changed on the fly.

Comment: Not work with `title = ^/?`, `title = "/?"`... either

Comment: wow.. after all these years knowing batch thinking i can do absolutely anything i cannot get it to work.. closest i have got was //? or '/?'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's possible with adding some invisible characters.
The idea is taken from @npocmaka [SO: How can I set set a title that start with coma,semicolon or equal sign?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30196991/463115)
The problem of a title with a starting comma it can be solved also with a LF character, but in your case the LF doesn't help anywhere in the string.

```
@echo off

(set LF=^
%=empty=%
)

::Create a FS variable
call :hexprint "0x1C" FS

title /%FS%?
exit /b

:hexPrint  string  [rtnVar]
  for /f eol^=^%LF%%LF%^ delims^= %%A in (
    'forfiles /p "%~dp0." /m "%~nx0" /c "cmd /c echo(%~1"'
  ) do if "%~2" neq "" (set %~2=%%A) else echo(%%A
exit /b
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@ECHO OFF
if "%~1"=="_SO42546112_" (
    shift
) else (
    start "/?" cmd /D /K ""%~f0" "_SO42546112_""
    exit
)
```

To launch a **new** `CMD` command prompt with `/?` window title, double click above `.bat` script.

---

To run a `.bat` script  with `/?` window title, use above concept e.g. as follows:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions

rem self wrapper - start
if "%~1"=="_SO42546112_" (
    shift
) else (
    start "/?" cmd /D /C ""%~f0" "_SO42546112_" %*"
    exit /B
    rem  ↑↑  omit the `/B` switch to close calling `cmd` window
)
rem self wrapper - end

rem check whether the self wrapper works - start   
echo 1st "%~1"
echo 2nd "%~2"
echo 3rd "%~3"
echo all %*
pause
rem check whether the self wrapper works - end

rem original script continues here:
```

Comment: Nice idea to use `start` instead of `title` to change the title